# sum with unite function tidyr

Tags: r

I was reading through the `tidyr` documentation. I'm trying to make use of the `unite` function. Is it possible to use the `unite` function to sum specified columns? Using the example from the documentation.

```
mtcars %>%
  unite(vs_am, vs, am)

                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs_am gear carb
Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46   0_1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02   0_1    4    4
Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61   1_1    4    1
```

I'm trying to figure how to get it so the vs_am isn't just the values combined as characters, rather it would add the values of the columns? Eg. for Mazda RX4, vs_am = 1 (because 0+1 = 1)

Comment: Maybe you want `dplyr::mutate`. `mtcars %>%
  dplyr::mutate(vs_am = vs + am)`

Comment: It would be something like this with `mutate`. `mtcars %>% rowwise %>% mutate(v_s = sum(vs + am))`

Comment: @jazzurro What does the rowwise function contribute ?

Comment: In this case, you don't need `rowwise`. If you use `rowwise`, you have operations for each row. Say if you want to find and take the max value of each row and put it in a new column, `rowwise` would be useful. `mtcars %>% rowwise %>% mutate(maxValue = max(mpg, dips))`

Comment: @user3900661 Pleasure.

Answer (score 4):

@Tyler is absolutely correct, unite is not the appropriate function for this task

Here is the code I was looking for
`mutate(vs_am = vs + am)`

```
   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb vs_am
1 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4     1
2 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4     1
```